# displaying data through jtextpane on the hit of button

Tags: java, swing

I have the below swing form now can you please advise i want that xml that is generated and stored in StringWriter i want that same string to be displayed in jtextpane itself on the hit of button named generate pleae advise how to achieve this..!!

```
public class sdr {

    private JFrame frmArgonNetworkModel;
    private final JButton btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel = new JButton("GenerateAgonNetworkModel");
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    private JTextField textField_5;
    private JTextField textField_6;
    private JTextField textField_7;
    private JTextField textField_8;
    private JTextField textField_9;
    private JTextField textField_10;
    private JTextField textField_11;
    private JLabel lblVer;
    private JTextField textField_12;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sdr window = new sdr();
                    window.frmArgonNetworkModel.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public sdr() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmArgonNetworkModel = new JFrame();
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().setForeground(new Color(188, 143, 143));
        frmArgonNetworkModel.setForeground(new Color(245, 222, 179));
        frmArgonNetworkModel.setTitle("Argon Network Model");
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().setBackground(UIManager.getColor("ToolBar.light"));
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel.setBackground(new Color(224, 255, 255));
        btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel.setBounds(226, 358, 196, 29);

        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Route CNA");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(22, 11, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblTyp = new JLabel("typ");
        lblTyp.setBounds(22, 36, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblTyp);

        JLabel lblSkcna = new JLabel("sk_cna");
        lblSkcna.setBounds(22, 83, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblSkcna);

        JLabel lblSktyp = new JLabel("sk_typ");
        lblSktyp.setBounds(22, 108, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblSktyp);

        JLabel lblSkver = new JLabel("sk_ver");
        lblSkver.setBounds(22, 133, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblSkver);

        JLabel lblPrefilterfilename = new JLabel("prefilterfilename");
        lblPrefilterfilename.setBounds(22, 158, 105, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblPrefilterfilename);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(122, 8, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(122, 33, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setBounds(122, 80, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);

        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setBounds(122, 105, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_3);
        textField_3.setColumns(10);

        textField_4 = new JTextField();
        textField_4.setBounds(122, 130, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_4);
        textField_4.setColumns(10);

        textField_5 = new JTextField();
        textField_5.setBounds(122, 155, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_5);
        textField_5.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("prefiltertype");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(22, 183, 88, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

        textField_6 = new JTextField();
        textField_6.setBounds(122, 180, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_6);
        textField_6.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("postfilterfilename");
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(22, 208, 88, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2);

        textField_7 = new JTextField();
        textField_7.setBounds(122, 205, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_7);
        textField_7.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("postfiltertype");
        lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(22, 233, 86, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_3);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_4 = new JLabel("xfm");
        lblNewLabel_4.setBounds(23, 258, 46, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_4);

        textField_8 = new JTextField();
        textField_8.setBounds(122, 230, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_8);
        textField_8.setColumns(10);

        textField_9 = new JTextField();
        textField_9.setBounds(122, 255, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_9);
        textField_9.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_5 = new JLabel("gelcatnumbersource");
        lblNewLabel_5.setBounds(22, 283, 116, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_5);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_6 = new JLabel("gelcatnumbersink");
        lblNewLabel_6.setBounds(22, 308, 88, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_6);

        textField_10 = new JTextField();
        textField_10.setBounds(122, 280, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_10);
        textField_10.setColumns(10);

        textField_11 = new JTextField();
        textField_11.setBounds(122, 305, 379, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_11);
        textField_11.setColumns(10);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setBounds(22, 398, 652, 157);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textPane);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.setBounds(100, 100, 711, 613);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel.setActionCommand("generate");

        lblVer = new JLabel("Ver");
        lblVer.setBounds(22, 61, 46, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblVer);

        textField_12 = new JTextField();
        textField_12.setBounds(122, 58, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_12);
        textField_12.setColumns(10);
        btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel.addActionListener(new ButtonClickListener());
    }

    public class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if ("generate".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                // create the Route object // marshal to string
                // ...

                Route route = new Route();
                //route.setCna( "cnavalue" );
                route.setCna(textField.getText());
                // route.setTyp("typ");
                route.setTyp(textField_1.getText());
                //route.setVer("ver");
                route.setVer(textField_2.getText());
                //route.setSk_cna("sk_cna");
                route.setSk_cna(textField_3.getText());
                //route.setSk_typ("sk_typ");
                route.setSk_typ(textField_4.getText());             
                //route.setSk_ver("sk_ver");
                route.setSk_ver(textField_5.getText());             
                //route.setPrefilterfilename("prefilterfilename");
                route.setPrefilterfilename(textField_5.getText());
                //route.setPrefiltertype("prefiltertype");
                route.setPrefiltertype(textField_6.getText());
                //route.setPostfilterfilename("postfilterfilename");
                route.setPostfilterfilename(textField_7.getText());
                //route.setPostfiltertype("postfiltertype");
                route.setPostfiltertype(textField_8.getText());
                //route.setGelcatnumbersource("gelcatnumbersource");
                route.setGelcatnumbersource(textField_9.getText());
                //route.setGelcatnumbersink("gelcatnumbersink");
                //route.setGelcatnumbersink(textField_9.getText());
                route.setGelcatnumbersink(textField_10.getText());

                try 
                {
                JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( Route.class );
                Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
                m.setProperty( "jaxb.fragment", true );
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                m.marshal( route, sw );
                   System.out.println( sw.toString() );
                }catch(Exception ee)
                {ee.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }


}
}
```

Comment: Add route class. It might not be necessary but without running your code it will be hard to explain what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you right but If you just want to add string to JTextField after pressing button you should use this:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
               textField.setText(yourString);
        }
});
```

Keep in mind that your textField should be final and code above is just a one way to achive this. You can also create new class which implements ActionListener interface and have access to button, jtextfield and string that you want to pun inside your component.